# ASP.NET Core Web API. The PUT endpoint is not getting hit using NSwag generated client

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

So I started learning Web API and ran into a problem with the PUT method. The PUT endpoint simply is not getting hit when I use the client that I generated with help of NSwag. I am using .NET 6.
Here is the controller:

```
using JournalEditService.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace JournalEditService.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class LessonEditController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly SchoolJournalContext _db;

        public LessonEditController(SchoolJournalContext db) 
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        [HttpGet("GetLessonByJournalAndDate/{fkJournal}/{date}")]
        public Lesson GetLessonByJournalAndDate(int fkJournal, DateTime date) 
        {
            return _db.Lessons.First(x => x.FkJournal == fkJournal && x.Date == date);
        }

        [HttpPut("UpdateLesson/{lesson}")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent)]
        public IActionResult UpdateLesson(Lesson lesson) 
        {
            if (lesson.Homework == null) 
            {
                lesson.Homework = "";
            }
            if(lesson.Theme == null) 
            {
                lesson.Theme = "";
            }
            _db.Lessons.Update(lesson);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return NoContent();
        }
        

    }
}
```

Lesson.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace JournalEditService.Models;

public partial class Lesson
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int FkJournal { get; set; }

    public int FkLessonTime { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public string Theme { get; set; } = null!;

    public string Homework { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual Journal FkJournalNavigation { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual LessonTime FkLessonTimeNavigation { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<Progress> Progresses { get; } = new List<Progress>();
}
```

And Program.cs file from another project, that uses the API

```
using JournalEditService.Models;
using Services;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Text.Json;

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var client = new Client("https://localhost:7051", httpClient);

Lesson lesson;
using(SchoolJournalContext db = new SchoolJournalContext()) 
{
    lesson = db.Lessons.First(x => x.Id == 2);
}
lesson.Homework = "Some homework";
string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(lesson);
var response = client.UpdateLessonAsync(json, lesson);
bool check = response.IsCompleted;
```

Generated client is too big to post here)

I think that is all. Let me know if you need some additional info and thanks for your help.

What makes this problem even more strange is that I tested that endpoint in Swagger UI and it works just fine, the problem happens only if I try to consume API with the client (GET methods work fine, the problem only with PUT and POST methods).

Comment: can you use `await` before `client.UpdateLessonAsync(json, lesson)` ?

Comment: @Orkad Hi. Added `await` and also deleted `var response = ` part, but now it returns a 'Bad request' exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Apparently the problem was with `[HttpPut("UpdateLesson/{lesson}")]`
part. Have edited it like this `[HttpPut("UpdateLesson")]` and it works fine.